# I can go back to modify my Character after I put the Armature

Tags: armature

So I put an armature on my complex character that I did in as part of a course. but I want to export it and I need to smooth the Normals. You can't do that with Armature Mode on, so how do I turn it off so that I can modify my model?

[image: gin]

[image]

Comment: You appear to be in Pose Mode (what you refer to as 'armature mode'). If you hit Tab, you should be able to choose to switch instead into another mode. You'll want Edit Mode or Object Mode to get back into the basic modeling pipeline, or perhaps Sculpt Mode. You can also control these options from the mouse-clickable menu in the bottom-left section of your 3D View window, which currently says "Pose Mode" in the image you posted.

Comment: I want to go in the basic edit mode

Comment: Yes -- follow the instructions in my comment and you will be able to do that. In case you found it hard to follow, I'm adding an answer with an image of where you should click.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment on your question, you appear to be in `Pose Mode` (which you referred to as 'armature mode'). If you hit `Tab`, you should be able to choose to switch instead into another mode. You'll want `Edit Mode` or `Object Mode` to get back into the basic modeling pipeline, or perhaps Sculpt Mode.

You can also control these options from the mouse-clickable menu in the bottom-left section of your `3D View` window, which currently says `Pose Mode` in the image you posted. You can find this menu at the location indicated below:

[image]

Comment: I just added a picture in edit mode but I can't still click on the figure without cliking on the armature

Comment: That's because the Armature is your currently active object. If you want to instead move into Edit Mode on the person model, you should switch back to Object Mode, and either select the person model in in the 3D View, or expand (click the little plus symbol) the Armature hierarchy in your Outliner tab (the menu in the top-right of your picture), find the personal model underneath it (assuming it is a Child Object of the Armature), and select the person model there. Once you have the person model selected in Object Mode, then switch to Edit Mode again.

Comment: Thank you soo much It worked

Comment: Great. Can you mark my answer as resolving your problem, so others know that it has been fixed?

Comment: How do we do that

Comment: To the left of my answer, I believe there should be a check mark that you can click in order to turn it green. Doing that indicates that you have accepted an answer as solving your problem.